# OpenCV mergevec issues

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

I'm running windows 7, and i'm trying to get some haar training done to make a haar classifier. I've got to the point were i need to merge a folder full of .vec files. I've been working on this for the better part of a day. I've tried following [coding robin's](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) tutorial but i get an error of:

```
g++.exe": pkg-config: No such file or directory  
g++.exe": opencv -I.: No such file or directory  
g++.exe": installation problem, cannot exec `cpp': No such file or directory
```

is this "installation problem" a problem with my g++ install? I'm still not sure.

those files (or directories) aren't in my opencv folder so i'm not really sure what to do about that. I vaguely remember reading that those were for if you were installing it with linux or something so i tried a different method.

I couldn't get [Naotoshi Seo's](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) to work because i can't download the mergevec.exe file anywhere. I always get a "your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now." I've done virus scans i've tried downloading from different computers and networks nothing works. since the previous method of compiling the mergevec.cpp file didn't work for me either, I then looked for yet another method where i found this tutorial[3] for using python. So I installed python 2.7.9 and ran this in command prompt

"C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\Recog_Project>python mergevec.py -v samples -o weed_samples.vec"

and i got this as a result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "mergevec.py", line 170, in <module>  
merge_vec_files(vec_directory, output_filename)  
File "mergevec.py", line 133, in merge_vec_files  
val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])  
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 12"
```

I don't know what to do anymore to try and get this to work.

I've tried installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine, but i can't even figure out how to change the resolution from 640:480. Ran these commands in terminal and restarted and got nothing.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

I also did something with some drivers but I can't remember what it was. basically this is my last hope. I'm out of ideas. I'll of course keep looking and for answers and will post any progress i make. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as my job is on the line. I could skype screen share if it would be helpful too.
Thanks in advance.

3: github.com/wulfebw/mergevec guess i need more rep to post additional links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered this within a few hours on the opencv Q&A. If you have any OpenCV questions i highly recommend you go there first as it is much more likely that someone will answer your question on their page. Here's the answer i received.

- You do not need to merge vec files for object classifier training using the cascade of weak classifiers approach. I keep wonder why the hell people merge vec files, and always the answer is because they want to create artificial data vectors. Avoid this at all costs if you want you models to do something with sense.
- Skip the complete haar training interface and move on to the traincascade  interface, which is better supported, more bugfree and better supported.
- Start with the traincascade and createsamples information in the [Description](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html?highlight=cascade%20classifier%20training).